# Async-kit and async.series is not a function

Tags: node.js

I'm trying async-kit to resolve some asyncronous problem.
My simplified code is:

```
var async = require('asynckit');

async.series([
  function( callback ) {
    console.log("print 1");
  },
  function(callback){
    console.log("print 2"}
])
.exec(function(error, result) {
    console.log("1 and 2 printed");
});
```

But the app returns: async.series is not a function
Why?

Comment: @cronvel : Please help me because, i'm sure, the problem is caused from my inexperience and not from your module!

Answer (score 0):

asynckit does not seem to have a `series` method. You are either looking for `async.serial` 
OR 
you have confused the `asynckit` module with the [`async`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) module, which does have the `series` function.